# How to create a dropdown menu in django with selections from created model objects?

Tags: django

I just want to create a dropdown menu with values from formerly created objects (instruments). In this case objects in the Instrument class. I read all the other posts about dropdowns in Django, but most of them address the creation of a new object or something with fixed choices. Though I want to select one from the available objects and then further process it. I don't want to create a new object and I need dynamic choices.

## forms.py

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

from .models import Instrument
from users.models import CustomUser

class CreateForm(forms.Form):
     instrument = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Instrument.objects.all())
     user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = CustomUser.objects.all())
     csv = forms.FileField()
```

## models.py

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    output_root = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    methods_root = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## html template

```
<!-- create.html --!>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Create new worklist</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="create-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

from .forms import CreateForm


def create_view(request):
    print('User:', request.user)
    form = CreateForm()
    return render(request, 'worklists/create.html', {'form': form})
```

The dropdown is not showing up. Only the label. Nothing to select though. There are Instruments created already. I tried Chrome and Firefox. The options appear in the rendered html page, but the drop down does not work.

[image]

## The rendered HTML page contains the options though:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Worklist Generator for Lewis Research Group</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="container center-align">
    <h1>Worklist Tool</h1>

      <p> Your are logged in as admin.</p> <a href="/logout"><button>Logout</button></a>

  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <h2>Create new worklist from csv-file</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="create-form"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="a77X7rnAY497SttoYosJ8Ao3pxQXe8Oes4aYfKXlBFV4KVEe6OSOhBpm2RGcClO3">
        <p><label for="id_instrument">Instrument:</label> <select name="instrument" required id="id_instrument">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">LUMOS</option>

  <option value="2">QED</option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_user">User:</label> <select name="user" required id="id_user">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="1">admin</option>

</select></p>
<p><label for="id_csv">Csv:</label> <input type="file" name="csv" required id="id_csv"></p>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>


      <br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? You see an error? Your code looks fine to me and should do what you want.

Comment: The dropdown is not showing up. Only the label. Nothing to select though. There are Instruments created already. I tried Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Weird. Check the HTML source of the page. No `<select>`?

Comment: From what you gave, it all seems to work fine in repl.it: https://repl.it/@browniebroke/Form-with-choices

Comment: you're not showing us the full story. The full form and the full view. Apparently some other code is messing up your form.

Comment: It is the full form. If something is not there that is missing, it is missing. I will add the view.

Comment: look at the HTML source in your browser, what do you see? Also did you actually create some `Instrument` in your db?

Comment: The instruments appear in the rendered html page. But it is not functional. Will add a screenshot.

Comment: Is this a bug??

Comment: No one knows what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style sheet set the display style to "none". Update your css and you're good to go.

[image: Screen Capture]

Comment: Yep, that was it!!! The materialize stylesheet has some unexpected settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Django Autocomplete Light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light)
it uses JavaScript select2

you can find what you exactly want in here:
[Create an autocomplete view](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#create-an-autocomplete-view)